# Is foldl ever preferable to its strict cousin, foldl'?

Tags: haskell, fold, strictness

Haskell has two left fold functions for lists: `foldl`, and a "strict" version, `foldl'`.  The problem with the non-strict `foldl` is that it builds a tower of thunks:

```
    foldl (+) 0 [1..5]
--> ((((0 + 1) + 2) + 3) + 4) + 5
--> 15
```

This wastes memory, and may cause a stack overflow if the list has too many items.  `foldl'`, on the other hand, forces the accumulator on every item.

However, as far as I can tell, `foldl'` is *semantically equivalent* to `foldl`.  Evaluating `foldl (+) 0 [1..5]` to head normal form requires forcing the accumulator at some point.  If we didn't need a head-normal form, we wouldn't be evaluating `foldl (+) 0 [1..5]` to begin with.

Is there any compelling reason one would want the behavior of `foldl` over that of `foldl'` ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`foldl` and `foldl'` are not semantically equivalent. Trivial counterexample:

```
Prelude Data.List> foldl (\x y -> y) 0 [undefined, 1]
1
Prelude Data.List> foldl' (\x y -> y) 0 [undefined, 1]
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

In practice, however, you usually want the strict `foldl'` for the reasons you mentioned.

Answer (score 14):

When `foldl` and `foldl'` wouldn't produce the same result, as in hammar's example, the decision has to be made according to the desired outcome. Apart from that, you'd use `foldl` rather than `foldl'` if the folded function is a constructor (applying a constructor creates a value in WHNF, there's no point in forcing it to WHNF again), and in `foldl (.) id functions` where forcing WHNF doesn't gain anything either. Apart from these exceptional cases, `foldl'` is the method of choice.

Comment: I don't believe there would ever be a reason to use `foldl (.) id functions` over `foldr (.) id functions`.  They are semantically equivalent, when the former is not `_|_`, so only the latter allows lazy consumption of the functions.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: @luqui: I think it's just the opposite. The foldr version looks like: `(\x acc -> x . acc)`, which will essentially mean: perform the *rightmost* function first, thus disallowing lazy consumption. Am I mistaken? :)

Comment: @DanBurton If the functions can start producing output without knowing their argument, `foldr` allows lazy consumption (consider `foldr (.) id [(string++) | string <- strings]`. @luqui Now you mention it, I don't know a reason to `foldl` (.) id functions` either.

Comment: @DanBurton, the order of information flow is potentially opposite that in a call by value language.  `f (g x)` only performs `g` "first" in your mind.  In fact it is `f` that has the first chance to produce information.  Consider `f x = 1:x`; `g x = g x`.

Comment: @luqui: ah yes, that makes sense. Playing with this idea has led me to ask [a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249958/folding-function-composition-monads-and-laziness-oh-my).