# Folding, function composition, monads, and laziness, oh my?

Tags: haskell, monads, fold, function-composition

I am puzzled. I can write this:

```
import Control.Monad

main = print $ head $ (foldr (.) id [f, g]) [3]
  where f = (1:)
        g = undefined
```

and the output is `1`. That makes sense, because it reduces to:

```
main = print $ head $ ((1:) . undefined . id) [3]
main = print $ head $ (1:) ((undefined . id) [3])
main = print $ head $ 1 : ((undefined . id) [3])
main = print $ 1
```

But if I use a vaguely similar monadic technique, it doesn't work the same:

```
import Control.Monad

main = print $ (foldr (<=<) return [f, g]) 3
  where f = const Nothing
        g = undefined
```

This hits `prelude.Undefined`. Which is odd, because I would expect it to reduce:

```
main = print $ ((const Nothing) <=< undefined <=< return) 3
main = print $ return 3 >>= undefined >>= (\_ -> Nothing)
main = print $ Nothing -- nope! instead, undefined makes this blow up
```

However, flipping the order of composition:

```
import Control.Monad

main = print $ (foldr (>=>) return [f, g]) 3
  where f = const Nothing
        g = undefined
```

does accomplish the expected short-circuiting and produces `Nothing`.

```
main = print $ (const Nothing >=> undefined >=> return) 3
main = print $ (const Nothing 3) >>= undefined >>= return
main = print $ Nothing >>= undefined >>= return
main = print $ Nothing
```

I suppose comparing the two approaches might have been comparing apples and oranges, but can you explain the difference? I thought that `f <=< g` was the monadic analogue to `f . g`, but they are apparently not as analogous as I thought. Can you explain why?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It depends on which monad you're working with, and how its `(>>=)` operator is defined.

In the case of `Maybe`, `(>>=)` is strict in its first argument, as Daniel Fischer explained.

Here are some results for a handful of other monads.

```
> :set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction
> let foo = (const (return 42) <=< undefined <=< return) 3
> :t foo
foo :: (Num t, Monad m) => m t
```

**Identity:** Lazy.

```
> Control.Monad.Identity.runIdentity foo
42
```

**IO:** Strict.

```
> foo :: IO Integer
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

**Reader:** Lazy.

```
> Control.Monad.Reader.runReader foo "bar"
42
```

**Writer:** Has both a lazy and a strict variant.

```
> Control.Monad.Writer.runWriter foo
(42,())
> Control.Monad.Writer.Strict.runWriter foo
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

**State:** Has also both a strict and a lazy version.

```
> Control.Monad.State.runState foo "bar"
(42,"*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
> Control.Monad.State.Strict.runState foo "bar"
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

**Cont:** Strict.

```
> Control.Monad.Cont.runCont foo id
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

Answer (score 19):

The bind for `Maybe` is strict in the first argument.

```
Just v >>= f = f v
Nothing >>= f = Nothing
```

So when you try

```
Just v >>= undefined >>= \_ -> Nothing
```

you hit

```
undefined v >>= \_ -> Nothing
```

and the implementation needs to find out whether `undefined v` is `Nothing` or `Just something` to see which equation of `(>>=)` to use.

On the other hand,

```
Nothing >>= undefined
```

determines the result without looking at the second argument of `(>>=)`.