# Does Haskell have foldlM'?

Tags: haskell, monads, fold

How does one fold over a monad strictly?  [`Data.Foldable`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Data-Foldable.html) has the strict `foldl'` and the monadic `foldlM`, but no strict `foldlM'`?  Is the strictness somehow defined by the monad itself?  If so, how does one work out what it is?

Imagine I must determine whether the product of an enormous list of ring elements is zero, but my ring isn't an integral domain, i.e. it contains zero devisors.  In this case, I should tail recursively `foldl` my multiplication `***` over the list, but return `False` the moment the product becomes zero, rather than waiting on the full product.

```
safelist :: [p] -> Bool
safelist [] = True
safelist (x:xs) = snd $ foldl' f (x,True) xs
   where  f (u,b) v = (w, b && w /= Zero)  where  w = u *** v
```

I could perhaps simplify this code slightly using the `Maybe` monad's `foldlM` but doing so seemingly lacks the required strictness.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no such standard function, but it's easy to define:

```
foldM' :: (Monad m) => (a -> b -> m a) -> a -> [b] -> m a
foldM' _ z [] = return z
foldM' f z (x:xs) = do
  z' <- f z x
  z' `seq` foldM' f z' xs
```

This is just the standard `foldM`, but with the same `seq`ing in it that `foldl'` does (compared to `foldl`). It's probably not defined anywhere standard because it's not likely to be all that useful: for most monads, `(>>=)` is "strict" in the sense you need to use a left-fold without overflowing the stack; this is only useful when your excessive thunks are in the returned values themselves, but a useful application of `foldM` will perform some monadic computation with the value from the last step, making that unlikely.

I think your code is simple enough as it is; I doubt `foldM'` would make it any more elegant.

Comment: Ahh, I suppose the monad could make things strict if it had strict flags in it, but not otherwise.  And no standard monads do so.  Thanks!

Comment: @JeffBurdges - here's sort of an ad-hoc observation of which Monadic `>>=` are strict vs lazy: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8250334/208257

Comment: Indeed, I doubt `foldM'` would help if your `(>>=)` is too lazy, since e.g. forcing a value returned by the lazy `State` monad doesn't necessarily force the state.