# How does this foldl-based function work: "myreverse = foldl (flip (:)) []"?

Tags: haskell, recursion, foldleft

I am learning haskell and I tried to write my own reverse function without using recursion.

The solution is this function:

```
myreverse = foldl (flip (:)) []
```

I'm trying to understand what happens during the evaluation of, say:

```
myreverse [1..5]
```

I can't understand what flip does here. Can somebody write down what happens here with a step-by-step explanation?

Comment: *I can't understand what `flip` does here.* You might benefit from writing `(:)` as a lambda: `\x xs -> x : xs`. If you apply `flip` to this lambda, the resulting function is `\xs x -> x : xs`.

Comment: protip: use `foldl'` from the List module instead of `foldl`. Plain `foldl` is never the best choice (unless you are solving some [crazy made up problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235797))

Comment: @hugomg, I think it should probably be perfectly fine in this case. `flip (:)` doesn't do any actual computation, so I'd expect GHC to treat it pretty much like a constructor. You'd have to test to be sure though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

flip is rather easy:

if you have a function `f :: a -> b -> c` then `flip f` is a function `:: b -> a -> c` so it gives you back a new function and **flips** the order of arguments you have to pass.

`(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]` is a function of this pattern and so `flip (:)` will now be a function that first takes the soon-to-be tail and then the new head and returns you a new list with those:

```
(flip (:)) [2..4] 1
= (:) 1 [2..4]
= 1 : [2..4]
= [1,2,3,4]
```

now you need this here because `foldl` is defined this way:

```
foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

you see - the function you have to pass will here be one that first takes a list and then an element and returns a new list

this will now fold all into something like this:

```
myreverse [1..5]
= foldl (flip (:)) [] [1,2,3,4,5]
= foldl (flip (:)) (((flip (:)) [] 1)) [2,3,4,5]
= foldl (flip (:)) (1:[]) [2,3,4,5]
= foldl (flip (:)) (((flip (:)) [1] 2)) [3,4,5]
= foldl (flip (:)) (2:[1]) [3,4,5]
= ...
= [5,4,3,2,1]
```

Comment: Minor objection: `foldl` doesn't cause the range to fully evaluate from the beginning.

Comment: yeah of course - but I think if I write down the sequence and look out for all the lazy parts this will get very cluttered and almost unreadable - I was hoping the indent and the way `flip` `(:)` and `foldl` are working here would be more obvious this way

Comment: Yes, yes, no problem. You wrote "something like this", after all.

Answer (score 3):

You might try in ghci what `flip` does:

```
:t (:)
(:) 1 [2..4]
```

> [1,2,3,4]

```
:t flip (:)
(flip (:)) [2..4] 1
```

> [1,2,3,4]